# xslt for powershell generated xml files

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I converted a JSON to XML via Powershell (Export-CliXml cmdlet) to this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="styles.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
     <MS>
      <Obj N="Attributes" RefId="1">
        <TNRef RefId="0" />
        <MS>
          <S N="SystemID">1013475</S>
          <S N="PrimaryName">Peter</S>
          <S N="Domain">3919.some-domain.com</S>
        </MS>
      </Obj>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

I want to use XSLT to view it Nicely: My attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html><head></head><body>



<p>some stuff</p>
<xsl:for-each select="Objs/Obj/MS/Obj/MS/S">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>



</body></html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Firefox and IE output just "some stuff" but nothing else. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I saved everything in UTF-8 w/o BOM

Comment: id remove the powershell tag -- the question is practically unrelated to PoSH

Comment: do you mean the namespace (xmlns)?

Comment: no, i mean the tags at the botton of your question: xml powershell xslt xpath

Comment: however, the removal of the xmlns-attribute worked perfectly. Thus, it is related to PoSH -

Comment: dont think thats oyur issue... i used to play quite a lot with xsl but some 15 years ago and dont remember ### ####. what do you mean by "the brwoser outputs just "some stuff""? -- sounds like your transformation is interpreted/saved/read as xml, not html and the browser is jyst missing a stylesheet

Comment: it looks like a *.txt-file where "some stuff" is written into. I have the `<p> some stuff </p>`, and only this was shown by the browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Answer was to remove the xmlns from the xml-file.

That is **not** the correct answer. XSL can transform *any* XML file, without requiring it to be modified first by some other means. Simply declare the namespace in your stylesheet, assign it a prefix and use that prefix to address the elements in the source XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"
exclude-result-prefixes="ps">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head/>
        <body>
        <p>some stuff</p>
        <xsl:for-each select="ps:Objs/ps:Obj/ps:MS/ps:Obj/ps:MS/ps:S">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I there a solution, which does not require to use `ps:` every time? this seems  very ugly

Comment: @Joel "*I there a solution, which does not require to use ps: every time?*" No, there isn't - at least not in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer was to remove the xmlns from the xml-file. `<Objs Version="1.1.0.1">` instead of `<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">` works like a charm. However... Why?

***UPDATE***:

The Solution I have now is the following: Insted of exporting the File via `(ConvertFrom-Json some_jsonstring) | Export-CliXml some-path` I use now: (from [this blog](https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/json-serializationdeserialization-in-powershell/)) the Convert-JsonToXML-Function.

**Benefits:**

1. Encoding of the output file is UTF-8 w/o BOM
2. No XMLNS Attribute is set
3. less code.